# Use gulp-replace-task to use replace in a php file (index.php)

Tags: gulp, gulp-rev, gulp-replace

I'm trying to use [gulp-replace-task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace-task) to replace text inside the `index.php` file. I know this can be done inside a `.html`, `.css` and `.js` file, but can't seem to get it working inside a `.php` file.

Can somebody please help me?

This is my code:

```
gulp.task('header', function() {

return gulp.src(rootPath + 'templates/header.php')

    .pipe(replace({
        patterns: [{
            json: {
                'main.css': 'style.css'
            }
        }]
    }))
    // Save the hashed css file
    .pipe(gulp.dest(rootPath + 'templates/header.php'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the "json" object to find/replace, use the RegEx syntax in the gulpfile.js below.  You'll end up with `build/php/templates/header.php` that contains the replaced text:

```
<?php
    $color = "blue";
?>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    Your color is <?php echo $color; ?>
<body>
```

## gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp')
var replace = require('gulp-replace-task')

var config = {
   src : 'src/php/**/*',
   build: 'build/php'
}

gulp.task('build', function(cb) {
   gulp.src(config.src)
      .pipe(replace({
         patterns: [
            {
               match: /COLOR/,
               replacement: 'blue'
            },
            {
               match: /main.css/,
               replacement: 'style.css'
            }
         ]
      }))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.build))

   cb()
})

gulp.task('watch', function(cb) {
   gulp.watch(config.src, ['build']) 
})

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'watch'])
```

## header.php

```
<?php
    $color = "COLOR";
?>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    Your color is <?php echo $color; ?>
<body>
```

## Project File Structure

```
$ tree -I node_modules
.
├── build
│   └── php
│       └── templates
│           └── header.php
├── gulpfile.js
├── package.json
└── src
    └── php
        └── templates
            └── header.php

6 directories, 4 files
```